# Foolproof way to install pig on cygwin

Tags: hadoop, cygwin, apache-pig

6Does anyone have a complete, explicit method to install - literally going from "not on my computer" to "on my computer and I can type 'pig -x local' and have it run without screwing up at all" - pig on a Windows machine running cygwin?

As of now, I've had to manually change several files, install hadoop separately, change more paths and files, and I'm still littered with error messages.

Does anyone have an explicit step-by-step process for doing this? I want to use pig at home as I use it liberally at work, but am about to give up after spending >10 hours trying to set this up fruitlessly.

I prefer to run pig locally, for what that's worth. It shouldn't be complicated, but it has proven to be not worth the time. Please help me find a foolproof way to do this.

(If one of your steps implies other steps, please list those other steps.)

Answer (score 0):

1) Download and Install [Oracle VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)

2) Download and Setup [Hortonworks Sandbox](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/#install) on your VBox

- Click "New" on your newly installed VirtualBox
- Select "Name"=[whatever you want], "Type"=Linux, and "Version"=Red Hat (64 Bit); click "Create"
- Click "Create" again
- Find your newly created Linux instance, click on it once and then click "Settings" up at the top.
- Navigate to "Storage"
- You should see something that says "Controller: SATA".  Click on whatever is below it, then go over to "attributes" and click on the blue disk, select "Choose a virtual hard disk file ..."
- Find the Hortonworks VM you downloaded in (2), select (Will be something like Hortonworks_Sandbox_2.x.vmdk) and click "OK".
- Click on your instance and click the green "Start" arrow.
  CentOS will boot (it takes awhile) and when it is done it will look like this

[image]

Hortonworks tells you exactly how to get to your instance.  Open up Cygwin and type `ssh root@localhost -p 2222`

Once you are in, type `$ pig -x local` and this should start up `Pig`.  Easiest way to practice with `Hive` and `Pig` IMO